# Debugging COM object initiated from VBA

Tags: c#, vba, excel, com

In Excel VBA one can create COM object by `CreateObject("NameSpace.InterfaceName")`.

Then calling function like `myComObject.DoStuff()`

Is there any way to set break point at `myComObject.DoStuff()` and start a Visual Studio to debug the function from here?

The Com object is written in C#.

Comment: Maybe by setting your DLL as startup project and the debug options to "start external program: <your VB app>" ? (or attaching to the process)

Comment: VS2008 says they can only debug an EXE file. XLS is not a valid executable file.

Comment: And if you use EXCEL.EXE as your executable? (or "EXCEL.EXE MYEXE.XLS" as command line)